# C++ Pointers and Vector

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I have a `vector<MyType*>*` and I'm not entirely sure how it is being accessed. I am declaring `MyType* var = new MyType(params)` and it is accessed fine in the class it was created in. The numbers spit out just fine. When I return a vector of those and attempt to access it from another class (`int main()` method), I am getting completely different numbers.

The way I am accessing it in `int main()` is

```
MyType* Temp = reinterpret_cast<MyType*>(&ReturnedVector[i]);
```

Is something miss pointed here? I'm new to C++.

EDIT: Adding code for clarification.
Here is my main method:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    MyAPI API;
    std::vector<MyClass*>* RetVector = API.GetVector();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < RetVector->size(); i++)
    {
        MyClass* Temp = reinterpret_cast< MyClass* >(&RetVector[i]);
        cout << Temp->value << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the vector returning method in a different class:

```
vector<MyClass*>* MyAPI::GetVector()
{
vector<MyClass*>* Ret = new vector<MyClass*>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
MyClass* Tmp = new MyClass(params);
Ret->push_back(Tmp);
}
return Ret;
}
```

Comment: Please put some code so as to understand, what exactly you are doing...

Comment: If that doesn't work without the cast than it's also wrong with a cast.

Answer (score 3):

You should not need the `reinterpret_cast`.  Any time you are doing that, think carefully about why you are doing it.  If it's to overcome a type warning the compiler is giving you, that warning may be entirely valid.

```
vector<MyType*> *ReturnedVector = some_function_that_returns_a_vector_pointer();

// NAUGHTY!
MyType* Temp = reinterpret_cast<MyType*>(&ReturnedVector[i]);
```

This is bad.  You assume that `ReturnedVector` is a pointer to an array of `vector<MyType*>`, and ask for the `i`th element of that array.  You then take the address of that element (`MyType**`) and cast it to `MyType*`.  It's no wonder your numbers are different.  You are lucky your program does not spit the proverbial dummy.

Note that `&ReturnedVector[i]` is the same as `ReturnedVector + i`.

Here's the correct method.  You dereference the pointer to get a `vector<MyType*>` and then call its array index operator to retrieve the `i`th element.  That element is a `MyType*` of course, and there's no need to cast.

```
// NICE!
MyType* Temp = (*ReturnedVector)[i];
```

---

Edit, since you have now posted some code...  A more common way to get a vector populated and returned from a function is to pass it by reference.  That way you don't deal with pointers to vectors and ugly dereferencing, and you don't need to delete the vector afterwards.  Try this:

```
void MyAPI::GetVector( vector<MyClass*> & vec )
{
    vec.clear();
    vec.reserve(100);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back( new MyClass(params) );
    }
}
```

---

Update.  When I wrote this answer, I wasn't very familiar with Return-Value Optimization, and as such I was paranoid about the potential copying that would take place when you return a vector.  This is actually not an issue.  The modern approach is to simply return the vector:

```
vector<MyClass*> MyAPI::GetVector()
{
    vector<MyClass*> vec;
    vec.reserve(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back( new MyClass(params) );
    }
    return vec;
}
```

And, as C++11 becomes more normal, we are beginning to abandon raw pointers in favour of `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` plus move-semantics:

```
vector<unique_ptr<MyClass> > MyAPI::GetVector()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<MyClass> > vec;
    vec.reserve(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back( std::move( unique_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass(params)) ) );
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: If pointers are _really_ needed they should probably be wrapped in an appropriate smart pointer or else one needs to manually delete them. Also in c++11, one should not really worry about returning the vector directly, as it will be moved and not copied. So the function signature should probably be std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> MyApi::GetVector(); or even std::vector<MyClass> MyApi::GetVector();.

Answer (score 0):

just replace this

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < RetVector->size(); i++)
{
    MyClass* Temp = reinterpret_cast< MyClass* >(&RetVector[i]);
    std::cout << Temp->value << std::endl;
}
```

with

```
while(!RetVector->empty())
{
    MyClass* Temp = RetVector->pop_back();
    std::cout << Temp->value << std::endl;
}
```